# A Punctuation Puzzle

Tags: riddle

Two characters used as one,
My end helps me go out with it,
My start is down with Stephen Hawking,
My start and middle is half of a questioning,
Half a shout, half a query, what am I, who am I really?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> an **Interrobang‽**

Two characters used as one

> It's an exclamation point combined with a question mark

My end helps me go out with it,

> Go out with a **BANG!**

My start is down with Stephen Hawking,

> Not entirely sure on this one.
> My only guess is that after Stephen Hawking's death, he was **INTER**red at Westminster Abbey?

My start and middle is half of a questioning,

> **INTERRO**gate

Half a shout, half a query, what am I, who am I really?

> Shout! + Query? = Interrobang‽

Comment: Whoa! That was amazing! So fast? You're correct on all of them, but an inter is something buried with a body, for example military honours.